# Getting e-mail adresses using a filter in Google Sheets /w scripts

Tags: gmail, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to extra email replies from gmail. I already found some code that is supposed to work.

**My question is**: how can one expand it to support a filter as a variable? (in this case so a filter is passed and *working* named z_lbl)

I am calling the function like so: `=listemails('test')`

But my error is sometimes: 'Formula parse error'; or I have also seen 'not allowed to use GmailApp.search'

IN the end I would like to make a function that I can call in my sheets. It takes 1 variable that I program either as a label finder (becomes label:searchme). Or even better: as a complete filter that is added as a search filter (becomes 'label:searchme has:attachment' etc).

Help is appreciated

```
function listEmails(z_lbl) { 
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/12029701/1536038  
  // get all messages      
  if (z_lbl == null) {
    throw 'Please add a label variable to the function to search for';
  }
  var eMails = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(
    GmailApp.search('label:'+z_lbl))
      .reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);})
      .map(function(eMails) {
    return eMails.getFrom() 
  });

  // sort and filter for unique entries  
  var aEmails = eMails.sort().filter(function(el,j,a)
    {if(j==a.indexOf(el))return 1;return 0});  

  // create 2D-array
  var aUnique = new Array();  
  for(var k in aEmails) {
    aUnique.push([aEmails[k]]);
  }

  // add data to sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, aUnique.length, 1)
    .setValues(aUnique);
}
```

Comment: The key line to achieve your goal is `GmailApp.search('label:'+z_lbl)`. A quick and dirty way that could work is to remove 'label:', then when you call the function pass as argument "a filter".

Comment: "make a function that I can call in my sheets" is not going to happen: custom functions called from a spreadsheet run without authorization, hence cannot access email.

Answer (score -1):

I created a sheet that uses filters that allow all kinds of exports.

Works great - hope it helps others

Shared here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14nOGCyu2nOLDQ_cJNQfVsDiBxy-Te3W8eh9du3C4sVQ/copy